# IIS Multidomain with asp.net and ef

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iis, subdomain

I have multiple domains (e.g. site1.my.domain, site2.my.domain etc) on an IIS8.5 on server 2012. They must share the same code-base to maintain updates easier. But the shall all have different databases (with code first EF). Is there a way that I can include or load different web.config in IIS depending on sub-domain? Or is there a way to create a connectionstring dynamically before EF opens it? (try different approaches, but as soon as I log in, it crashes because no host/Request/Session available in Code.

Thanks in advance
Carsten

Comment: Try looking at `Request.ServerVariables['HTTP_HOST']`.  It gives the name of the current domain.  Look at where EF sets the connection string (maybe global.asax).

Comment: Well. Problem is, that this works as long as its a normal request. But in Postback (tested by login...) the ApplicationDbContext is opend at least trice. Two time the proposed works. The third time Context - and therefore Request and Server - are NULL. *sigh*

Comment: For the third request (Context) is there something additional that you need to process (read/write/output)?  Maybe it is logically possible to ignore the third, and handle processing & output on the first 2 requests. Maybe.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe the first two requests give you an opportunity to set a session variable to hold the domain name, or an OAUTH token entry or something.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Sadly I can't set a Session-Var, because on the third, there is no Context (HttpContext.Current) and therefore neither Request nor Session. But I found out, whi makes that third call to the constructor: EF with automatic Migrations. Darn. Now. How to make Automatic Migs manuel ;-)

Comment: OK. And found the solution for that problem: On SetInitializers<DbContext,Config>() just put a true in the brackets... Darn... So easy... 2 days...

Comment: You should put that answer below, because it could help other folks on StackOverflow with the same problem.  And you could earn reputation points.  btw, nice work on persevering and solving it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. And found the solution for that problem: On SetInitializers() just put a true in the brackets... Darn... So easy... 2 days...